# Dynamically inherit from instance of the class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I am kind of struggling with inheritance in JavaScript. Let's say I have a following class:

```
class Parent {
  constructor({ name, someOtherStuff } = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.someOtherStuff = someOtherStuff;
  }

  someMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and I would like to create a decorator that would allow me to do following:

```
@parent({
  name: 'foo',
  someOtherStuff: 'bar'
})
class MyClass extends Component {
  myMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();

// Those tests must pass
expect(instance.someMethod).toBeFunction();
expect(instance.name).toEqual('foo');
expect(instance.someOtherStuff).toEqual('bar');
expect(instance.myMethod).toBeFunction();
expect(instance instanceof Parent).toBe(true);
expect(instance instanceof MyClass).toBe(true);
```

Is there a way to create such decorator? I tried multiple solutions, but none of them really satisfies all the tests.

```
const parent = (...args) => (Target) => {
  // Target corresponds to MyClass
  const parent = new Parent(...args);

  // ...
};
```

lodash is allowed.

Comment: By "decorator", you mean python like decorator?

Comment: @Arnial: https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/master/README.md .

Comment: I mean: https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators

Answer (score 3):

Why use decorators? You can just extend parent class

```
class MyClass extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super({name: 'foo', someOtherStuff: 'bar'});
    }
}
```

Comment: He is exploring a new feature of the language and would like to know if he can use it in a certain way but is having difficulties. He's not asking how to do it the traditional way.

Comment: I need a decorator, because it suppose to be a feature of a library I build. Additionally It will be used together with react components that already inherit from Component class

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorators to create a new class that inherits, apply some mixins, and go from there. JS classes don't have mutliple inheritance, so you can't do this directly, but you can combine the two manually or create a proxy that will do what you want.

I've been using wrapper classes for a [decorator-based DI library](https://github.com/ssube/noicejs) by returning a class [like so](https://github.com/ssube/noicejs/blob/master/src/main/Wrapper.js#L13):

```
static wrapClass(target, {hook = noop} = {}) {
  return class wrapper extends target {
    static get wrappedClass() {
      return target;
    }

    constructor(...args) {
      super(...Injector.fromParams(args).getDependencies(wrapper).concat(args));
    }
  }
```

}

The decorator is really returning a new constructor with closure over the original, but that's enough for most purposes.